# How to disable SHIFT + F10 keyboard shortcut in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever I press `SHIFT` + `F10`, it brings up a menu (shown in the picture) on the right side of the screen.

How can I turn off this behavior, or at least change the shortcut to something else?
I would like to use `SHIFT` + `F10` in JetBrains IDEs instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not appear to be a standard Windows shortcut. Standard Windows hotkeys, with the exception of the Ctrl+Alt+Del sequence, can be overridden by any application.

If you are on a laptop, the F-keys are often repurposed into media keys and you may need to additionally press an Fn key to get the F# function. See if there is an alternative function printed on the key, often in blue. You may be able to change the default (for the whole bar) in the firmware/BIOS settings. Some laptop models let you toggle the Fn-lock on the fly with combinations such as Fn+Esc.

If this is a Fn/media key issue, unfortunately the possibility and specific method of changing it will differ depending on the laptop. There are other somewhat clunkier ways (e.g. with AHK).

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is a laptop (Lenovo V320), and I can use `SHIFT` + `F10` + `Fn` to get the desired behavior indeed. The `F10` button has a symbol printed on it, showing two screens. I suppose it means it's used for the screen mirroring functionality which can be seen in the picture I posted too. I also tested it now without pressing `SHIFT` (pressing `F10` in itself), it has the same functionality. I'll try to look for a solution specific to my hardware. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @user3738870 Lenovo laptops typically provide the option to switch the whole bar in firmware/BIOS. Otherwise you can use AHK to see which scancode the media key sends, and remap that back to F10.

Comment: Yes, I managed to disable all of the hotkeys in BIOS. Thanks again