# How to disable Shift + F10 Windows 10 shortcut key in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a very similar question to what was asked before in [How to disable SHIFT + F10 keyboard shortcut in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1486128/how-to-disable-shift-f10-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-10). But the answer wasn't relevant to my quest. Pressing shift + F10 brings context menu. I've already tried to disable it by using sharpkeys and autohotkeys, but it didn't work. Trying both, I was able to disable my context menu button on my keyboard but not Shift + 10. I appreciate if someone could help me to disable the shortcut key? Thanks.

The list of Windows 10 Shortcut Keys - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

[The snapshot of the shortcut key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD7Jj.png)

Comment: What context menu does it display exactly?

Comment: The same menu that you get when you right click. I tried following the article in <https://www.howtogeek.com/425623/what-is-the-menu-key-for-and-how-to-remap-it/>. But, it didn't work!

Comment: Wow! Very interesting that it doesn't do anything in your version. No, I haven't installed any 3rd party to produce the effect. When I was searching online, it seems to be a common windows 10 feature.

Comment: To be clear it does nothing on the desktop without anything selected.  This was the reason I wanted to know why it looked like (screenshot)